# The integral of the arc length squared

Tags: calculus, parametric, arc-length

Given the length of a parametric curve, $l=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt { ( { {dx} \over {d \theta}} )^2 + ( { {dy} \over {d \theta}} )^2} d\theta $.  Does  $l^2=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} ( { ( { {dx} \over {d \theta}} )^2 + ( { {dy} \over {d \theta}} )^2} )d\theta $ ?  Is there a simple explanation why $ g = \int f dx $, $g^2 $ doesn't equal $\int f^2 dx$?

Comment: Absolutely not, otherwise there would be no reason to ever put a square root.

Comment: Definitely not. The length l is a function of $\theta_2$ and $\theta_1$ in general. What do you mean by the integral of $l^2$ in that case - which variable are you integrating against? Maybe you are trying to find some kind of area? In that case you need to look at double integration.

Comment: I mis spoke / typed.  I meant to say "is $l^2$ equal to the second integral.

Comment: Same answer - definitely not. Working out the length is often difficult due to the squareroot and you can't wish it away.

Comment: My actual problem is that I need to solve for an ellipse with the arc length specified, passing through two points, in real time, and my current solution takes too long.  The points and specified time are updated in real time.

Comment: This integral is solved by... the elliptic integral function :)

Comment: There is no closed formula for the arc length of an ellipse. You will need to calculate it numerically e.g simpson's method

Comment: Thanks for the comments and information.